# How to create a simple POC for an api's request and response?

Tags: java, android, api

I am new to android and java.I need a basic proof of concept of a working api.so that we can measure time to get http response after a request

Comment: And your question is basically super braod, and not at all clear. Do you want to write an Android app that invokes some 3rd party endpoint? Or do you want to measure the performance of your API endpoint just with Java? Seriously: step back, and turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here.

Comment: just want to check performance or response time of api

Comment: And how is that related to Android or Java? You see, you are expected to do research prior posting questions here. This isn't a free tutoring service where people sit down with you to walk/work through all aspects of your project. So: what prevents you picking up a tutorial for your desired programming language etc ... and just start trying?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving you a programatical answer , I can give you some pointers that can help you to code.

You need to develop following parts to accomplish your requirement.

1. A small SpringBoot application
2. A REST controller in the SpringBoot application.
   3  An HTTP GET method in your REST controller.
3. The GET method should calculate the execution time using Java Instant class(only available from Java 8).
4. The GET method should return the execution time.
5. A  RestTemplate based client application to call above REST API and print the time elapsed.

Comment: OP asks for ANDROID.